# Maven path not changing to custom location in STS on Windows 7

Tags: maven

I would like to change default maven's .m2 folder location due to some reasons. I have done the following changes.
 1. /path/to/local/repo changed as D:\HAWB\settings.m2\repository in conf/settings.xml
 2. In STS, Window --> maven --> Installations --> Add. Here added Maven 3 path.
 3. Copy pasted settings.xml from maven installation to D:\myname.m2\repository location
 4. In STS updated Maven --> User Settings to "D:\myname.m2\repository\settings.xml"

When I am running my application through STS 3.x, its downloading all the jars into C:\Users\myusername.m2\repository. But when run the same application through cmd prompt, its downloading to custom location set above.

Please let me know, if I missed any other setting to be set in STS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I foundout the issue, migrated to Maven 3 and in Run configuration for Arguments tab, I am still referring Maven 2 path. 
-Dmaven.home=